# Mapping a String to an Array

Tags: javascript

Given a string delimited by commas, how would I go about splitting it into an array in javascript?

Comment: +1 for using the split keyword in asking how to do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

var array = *string*.split(",") should do it where string is your string variable

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use the [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method on your string:

```
var myString = 'a,b,c';
var myArray = myString.split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

You use [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp). As in `var myArray = "a,b,c".split(',');`